Kloosterman Sum expansion in Iwaniec's Book
I am currently reading Iwaniec's book on the Spectral Theory of Automorphic Forms:

I have two  questions from In Section 3.4 third line, which says
\begin{align}
E_a(\sigma_bz|p) & =
\sum_{\gamma\in B\setminus\sigma_a^{-1}\Gamma\sigma_b/B}
p(\gamma z)
\\[3mm] & = \delta_{ab}p(z)+\sum_{c > 0}\sum_{d\left(\!\!\!\mod\!\! c\right)}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}p(\omega_{cd}(z+n))
\end{align}
According to theorem $\bf 2.7$ Statement, $\omega_{d/c}$ should come instead $\mbox{of}\ \omega_{cd}$.
Also on the next line how this comes,
$$
\omega_{cd}(z+t)=\frac{a}{c}-\frac{1}{c^2}\left(t+x+iy+\frac{d}{c}\right)^{-1}
$$
My guess is may be he is working with some other cusp but I am not sure.

Any insight or hints would be very helpful.

In the book it is $\omega_{cd}$, and not $w_{cd}$. But yes, this is not the point. It is better of you don't use pictures, see
here,
why. Use MathJax.
